# ngAnimate not adding ng-enter class to ng-view in Angular 1.2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-animate, ng-view

I have been scouring the web for an answer to this but I cannot seem to find any definitive answers.

The problem seems to be that the ngAnimate directive is not adding the classes `ng-enter` or `ng-leave` when the route is changing. I have created a test application and included the `ngAnimate` directive to the app. I also created the animate class and applied the class to the `ng-view` element

The link to my test application is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/6qCMeIkWeXeTQyDWcu29?p=preview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply add each vendor's prefix for each browser e.g. chrome's `-webkit` in your css file

**[FORKED PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/iSCxYvi4i2Ulo1UKyHn1?p=preview)**

```
.slide.ng-enter, .slide.ng-leave{
  position: absolute;
}

.slide.ng-enter { 
  animation: slideInRight 0.5s both ease-in; z-index: 8888; 
  -webkit-animation: slideInRight 0.5s both ease-in; z-index: 8888; 
}
.slide.ng-leave { 
  animation: slideOutLeft 0.5s both ease-in; z-index: 9999; 
  -webkit-animation: slideOutLeft 0.5s both ease-in; z-index: 9999; 
}


@keyframes slideOutLeft {
    to      { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideOutLeft {
    to      { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}


@keyframes slideInRight {
    from    { transform: translateX(100%); }
    to      { transform: translateX(0); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideInRight {
    from    { transform: translateX(100%); }
    to      { transform: translateX(0); }
}
```

Comment: Wow! I can't believe that's what the problem was. I was hitting my head against a wall for ages for this! I thought that since it wasn't even adding the appropriate class that it was something wrong with Angular. Thank you for your help1

Comment: What! I've been hitting my head with the keyboard from the past 3 hours. Even I thought this was Angular's (non-css related) fault and was scouring the Internet for a solution from that angle. Isn't this an Angular bug?

Comment: Did the same thing - was tearing my js to pieces thinking it was an angular bug... stupid css! haha